# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment - Solution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've looked through other situations online about this issue I'm having, but none of them really gave me a solution as to what I'm looking to be solved. I currently have a button set up so that if someone presses it, I want the symbol, in this case, a plus sign, to be printed into the input box, but currently, my line of code is not giving me the solution.
For my calculator, I managed to successfully pull it off with my number pad, but when it came to the symbols, I don't know what's going on. When I check the console, it was giving me the error of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" whenever I had pressed the plus button.

```
<form name = "clear-console">
<input type = "number" id = "input" placeholder = "0">
  <input type = "button" value = "4" onClick = numbers(4) class = "number-pad"></button>
  <input type = "button" name = "add" class = "number-pad" value = "+" onclick = "clear-console.display.value += '+'">   //this line of code
</form>
```

Any solutions to what I'm going for? Am I missing something in the code?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is `clear-\`` supposed to do? And what is `console.display`?

Comment: @D.Pardal I'm sorry, the ' shoudln't be after the clear-. It's supposed to be "clear-console". That's the name I gave my form for the "Clear all" function for my calculator.

Comment: Oh, function names cannot contain `-`. That's your problem. Maybe you meant `_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form name = "clearConsole">  <! –– Remove `-` to make it a valid variable name in JavaScript ––>
<input type = "text" id = "input" placeholder = "0" name="display">  <! –– You are missing `name` for reference of this input ––>
  <input type = "button" value = "4" onClick = numbers(4) class = "number-pad">
  <input type = "button" name = "add" class = "number-pad" value = "+" onclick = "clearConsole.display.value += '+'">   // Now this works.
</form>
```

You are missing `name` for the number input. Also you'd better avoid using `-` in the form name, as that is not allowed in JavaScript variable names.

Also, you need to change the type of that input to `text`, or it will not be able to display `1+` after you added.

Answer (score 0):

While a hyphen `-` can be used in HTML attributes, it can't be referenced from JavaScript since it's an operator.

Replace it with an underscore `_` (or use *camelCase*) and you'll be fine.